# Visual Studio Setup Project - possible values for "DefaultLocation"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

What is the list of possible values for "DefaultLocation" like "[ProgramFilesFolder]"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a list by myself @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa372057.aspx

from that page:

**AdminToolsFolder**    The full path to the directory that contains administrative tools.
**AppDataFolder**   The full path to the Roaming folder for the current user.
**CommonAppDataFolder** The full path to application data for all users.
**CommonFiles64Folder** The full path to the predefined 64-bit Common Files folder.
**CommonFilesFolder**   The full path to the Common Files folder for the current user.
**DesktopFolder**   The full path to the Desktop folder.
**FavoritesFolder** The full path to the Favorites folder for the current user.
**FontsFolder** The full path to the Fonts folder.
**LocalAppDataFolder**  The full path to the folder that contains local (nonroaming) applications.
**MyPicturesFolder**    The full path to the Pictures folder.
**PersonalFolder**  The full path to the Documents folder for the current user.
**ProgramFiles64Folder**    The full path to the predefined 64-bit Program Files folder.
**ProgramFilesFolder**  The full path to the predefined 32-bit Program Files folder.
**ProgramMenuFolder**   The full path to the Program Menu folder.
**SendToFolder**    The full path to the SendTo folder for the current user.
**StartMenuFolder** The full path to the Start menu folder.
**StartupFolder**   The full path to the Startup folder.
**System16Folder**  The full path to folder for 16-bit system DLLs.
**System64Folder**  The full path to the predefined System64 folder.
**SystemFolder**    The full path to the System folder for the current user.
**TempFolder**  The full path to the Temp folder.
**TemplateFolder**  The full path to the Template folder for the current user.
**WindowsFolder**   The full path to the Windows folder.
**WindowsVolume**   The volume of the Windows folder.